# Using Collection Filter to then be used in Delete Action (flow)

Tags: visual-workflow, delete, account-teams, recordtriggeredflow, collection-variable

I'm building a Record Triggered - After Save flow.

In the flow I have a GET element that is

1. gathering all AccountTeamMember records with a specific Account Id. (getCurrentAccountTeamMembers)
2. filtering that Record Collection based on the Team Role. (Debug output below)

This is where I'm running into issues:

3. I have a decision to see if records exist in the filtered collection variable - however, utilizing `AccountTeam from FindCurrentDataBD IS NULL = False` in the decision does not accurately calculate if there are records found in the record collection - is there a way to do this? I can see whether records are found when I do a debug - but they're being presented in a way that I am not able to compare against. (See below)
   It'll work if Records exist fine - but if a record does not exist it'll still evaluate to true & then the flow fails.
4. I then want to them delete the filtered collection list if records exist.

Collection Filter debug Output:

```
Source collection: getCurrentAccountTeamMembers
Create a collection, applying these filter conditions

All conditions must be true (AND)
{!currentItem_FindCurrentDataBD_0.TeamMemberRole} (null) Equals Data BD
Items in source collection: 1
Items in filtered target collection: 0
Result

None.
```

Decision Output:

```
Outcome executed: Found
Outcome conditions

{!FindCurrentDataBD} ([]) Is null false
All conditions must be true (AND)
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that filter works correctly for the debug example you have mentioned but you are unable to check if it is empty or not.

Checking whether filtered collection is null or not works. I say you are comparing wrong collection to null. The collection you are comparing it to is the original one.